# EventLog.Source and EventLog.Delete(logName): Are "Source" and "logName" referring to the same property?

Tags: c#, .net, event-log

In reading about creating custom event logs, I came across something that is somewhat confusing.

When creating a custom event log, one property you need to set is the `Source`, which apparently is any name you want to give to the log. When writing and reading to this custom log, you will specify this "Source".

When deleting a log, you also need to provide a string parameter, but this one is called `logName`. These seem like the same thing.

Is this logName and the "Source" you originally specified the same propery? If so, why are they named differently (i.e. why isn't the parameter for the delete method just called "Source")? If not, what are they, how are they related?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No they are not. `Source` specifies what "application" or "source" is writing to the log. `LogName` is the actualy log name to write/read/delete.